# Magento 2.4.2-p1 local setup on Windows system - issue with _view folder in pub directory

Tags: localhost, windows, pub, magento2.4.2-p1

I am trying to setup Magento 2.4.2-p1 on local windows system and running following commands after code and database setup:

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- php bin/magento c:f

I have ran these commands multiple times and every time the css and js file URL is containing **_view**, which is not coming on production website's css and js URL,

Anyone could help on this why **_view** is coming in css an js files URL.

Comment: Gourav Yadav iam also getting this like in remote server due to this my page is breaking did you get any solution.

Comment: No Sabareesh, still I didn't get any solution for the same.